# Is {(1,1), (1,2),(1,3),(3,3)} transitive?

Tags: relations

Is the relation R = {(1,1), (1,2),(1,3),(3,3)} transitive?

The definition of transitive relation is; if (a,b) and (b,c), then (a,c). but there is no (b,c). Does it make R transitive?

Comment: Yes, it's transitive.

Comment: Note, $a,b,c$ do not need to be distinct.  They could all be the same, two of them the same in whatever order, or all distinct.  Your relation is transitive.  For a different example the relation $\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$ is not transitive because although $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ are in the relation you have that $(1,1)$ is not.  Here, $a,b,c$ are $1,2,1$ respectively.

Comment: A rephrasing of transitivity using concepts from graph theory: Any *directed* path you can travel between elements of the relation along the directed edges of the relation, regardless of distance, must be traversable in a single step.  Like how if $a<b$ and $b<c$ and $c<d$ and $d<e$, you must have that $a<e$ (*as well as several others*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're saying that $R$ is transitive because we never see any situation that transitivity applies to: e.g. if we had $(1, 2),(2,3)\in R$ then transitivity would require that $(1,3)$ be in $R$, but you're saying that this situation never occurs and hence $R$ is *(vacuously)* transitive.

This isn't quite right - there *are* transitivity-relevant situations. In fact, there are exactly two:

- $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$ are in $R$ (in this case $a=1, b=1, c=2$).
- $(1, 3)$ and $(3, 3)$ are in $R$ (in this case $a=1, b=3, c=3$).

However, each of these are "silly" in a precise sense. Namely, they don't lead to anything *new*: the first says that in order for $R$ to be transitive we must have $(1,2)\in R$, and the second says that in order to be transitive we must have $(1,3)\in R$, but each of these *required instances* is already present in the *situation described*. This is an example of a more general phenomenon:

> Suppose $R$ is such that whenever we have $(a,b),(b,c)\in R$, either $a=b$ or $b=c$. Then $R$ is transitive.

So while $R$ isn't quite vacuously transitive, it's still transitive in a kind-of-vacuous way: it has no *serious* instances to which transitivity applies.

So I would say that your reasoning is in the right direction, but isn't quite right. Your conclusion, however, is correct: $R$ is indeed transitive.